# I'm getting this annoying email every 2 minutes

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting this annoying email every 2 minutes

> Your script, Auto Update - Binance, has recently failed to finish
>   successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure
>   the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving
>   future failure notifications, click here.
>
> The script is used by the document Copy of Crypto tracking - Binance
>   (template).
>
> Start Function    Error Message   Trigger End 10/7/18 12:30 AM    log Invalid
>   argument: key (line 43, file "Code")  time-based  10/7/18 12:30 AM
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Google Apps Script

Even I've deleted that document 'Copy of Crypto tracking - Binance (template)'

Comment: Remove the authorization to the script file in your account settings for security.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google Drive trash / bin an delete the files permanently.

Alternatively, you could

1. Restore the file from the trash
2. Open the file
3. Click on Tools > Script editor
4. Click on Edit > Triggers from the active project
5. Click on the X button of the corresponding trigger to delete it.